# Can I Restore data from ORACLE datafiles folder?

Tags: oracle, database-restore, tablespace, data-files

my server had been attacked by a ransomware .rapid and all my data had been encrypted , luckily for me the oracle home folder is not encrypted - yet - and most of the files including the **datafiles** folder and tablespaces are still accessible

Can any One please tell me how to recover my database objects?
no backup is available , only oracle home folder -most of it-

EDIT :
The System is broken , I am trying to know witch files to collect and copy that will enable me to recover my database files from another system

when I try to log into **sqlplus** throw cmd I get the following error :

> 'sqlplus' is not recognized as an internal or external command ,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Blockquote

EDIT :
[FILES THAT I STILL HAVE ACCESS TO - NOT ENCRYPTED -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS5fK.png)

Comment: More details, please. Are you trying to recover on the same server, or a different one? Do you still have copies of your control file? Do you have a pfile (initialization parameter file, init.ora)? What about the redo logs / archive logs? For a basic overview, research how to clone a database. http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_db_copy.htm

Comment: @kfinity
thanks for the advice
"_research how to clone a database_"
on my way to do so

Comment: @kfinity
do you mean the _control file_ that is located in the datafiles folder?

Comment: @kfinity 
I have updated the question with an attachment that shows the files that I still have access to

Comment: So all your data is on the USERS tablespace?

Comment: @APC --My data is on the SYSAUX--

MY DATA IS IN THE DEFAULT TABLESPACE

Comment: Well that's really bad practice, and contra-indicated in the Oracle documentation. But probably the least of your worries right now.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. If you can find an `init.ora` file on your server, that's the PFILE - initialization parameter file - that's the last thing missing to easily copy your database to a new server. If you can't find it, that's ok - it'll just be a little harder. As long as you have the datafiles, you can eventually get your database back.

Basically, [you'll want to follow steps 2-8 in the link I posted](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_db_copy.htm). You can also find some helpful info in [the Oracle guide to manually creating a database in Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e10845/create.htm#NTQRF133). I'll walk you through them.

1. Shutdown your old database (if it's still running). This will make sure your datafiles are in a consistent state for copying. Probably stopping the Windows Service would be the easiest way to do that if you can't access `sqlplus`.
2. Copy the data to your new server. I'm assuming it'll be in the same location, `D:\app\Administrator\oradata\VTC\`
3. Make a copy of the control file `CONTROL01.CTL` and name it `create_db.sql` (EDIT: I was assuming that this was a `backup to trace` ascii version of the control file, but it sounds like this is the binary file)
4. Edit `create_db.sql`. Where it says `CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "MY_DB" NORESETLOGS`, change it to `CREATE CONTROLFILE SET DATABASE "MY_DB" RESETLOGS`. Make note of whatever `"MY_DB"` is - this is your database name. Most people make it the same as the SID. I normally do `RESETLOGS` which throws out the old redo logs, but you could try keeping them with `NORESETLOGS` if that works for you.
5. Remove or comment out the lines that say `RECOVER DATABASE` and `ALTER DATABASE OPEN;`. Make sure the paths for the datafiles and logfiles look correct. Save the file.
6. If you couldn't find your `init.ora` to copy, I *think* this very minimal one will work for you, although you'll want to fix your memory settings later. Create it in the same folder.

> ```
> DB_NAME=MY_DB
> INSTANCE_NAME=MY_DB
> SERVICE_NAMES=MY_DB
> CONTROL_FILES = ("D:\app\Administrator\oradata\VTC\CONTROL01.CTL")
> DB_FILES=100
> ```

7. Create an Oracle Database Windows Service. Afterwards check Services to make sure it's running.

   `oradim -NEW -SID MY_DB -STARTMODE manual -PFILE "D:\app\Administrator\oradata\VTC\init.ora"`
8. Log in to your new Oracle instance as SYSDBA. There's no database yet.

   `cd D:\app\Administrator\oradata\VTC\
   set ORACLE_SID=MY_DB
   sqlplus / as sysdba`
9. Create the database, using the control file from the old server as a script.

   `@create_db.sql`
10. If everything comes back OK, run:

    `alter database open`

Comment: thank you very much for your help , but on step #4 when i try to open **create_db.sql** with text editor _I dont find  Where it says **CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "MY_DB" NORESETLOGS**_ , I just find a strange code in the file nothing readable

Comment: did you mean the **trace file** instead of CONTROL01.CTL  here >>  `3- Make a copy of the control file ` _**CONTROL01.CTL**_  `and name it create_db.sql`

Comment: you're right, I meant a trace backup of the control file. I think you might be able to reuse the binary control file and start up the database if all the datafile / log file locations are the same, but I've never tried it.

Comment: how to do that please , not a detailed instructions , just the flow of actions cuz I'm really lost right now

Comment: 1. copy datafiles to the new host device
2.install oracle 12c on that device( **should I install only the database tools** ?)
3. what next ?? I dont know how to create the new database without the script that should be generated by `alter database backup controlfile to trace` ??

Comment: I think you'll want to ignore steps 3-5. Do steps 6, 7, 8 if you can. Then the basic idea is to do `startup nomount` and then run a `CREATE CONTROLFILE ...` statement, which is what `backup to trace` normally creates. See the example at the end here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5004.htm#SQLRF01203

Comment: That'll overwrite the existing controlfile. If you want to try reusing your existing control file, I think you could just try skipping step 9? See if you can startup and open the db.